# javascript arrays, how to change this array structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 3 arrays in javascript. I'd like to combine them all into 1 var, but name each item (like PHP's associate array). So the first item is red, second is green, third is blue. And then how do I call each item separately after?

```
[[2, 1], [4, 1], [10, 1], [19, 1]],
[[3, 1], [14, 1], [18, 1], [19, 1]],
[[7, 1], [6, 1], [8, 1], [17, 1]]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var combined = {
    red: [[2, 1], [4, 1], [10, 1], [19, 1]],
    green: [[3, 1], [14, 1], [18, 1], [19, 1]],
    blue: [[7, 1], [6, 1], [8, 1], [17, 1]]
};
```

Then you can access the arrays as `combined.red`, `combined.green`, and `combined.blue`.

Comment: Similarly to PHP's associative arrays, you can also access it like `combined["red"]`, `combined["green"]`, and `combined["blue"]`.